# Granados SSH Library and ForwardAgent directive

Tags: c#, authentication, ssh

When using the [Granados](http://granados.sourceforge.net/) C# SSH Library, is there any way to set the ForwardAgent directive to true?

The library works perfectly for me, but I need to use it when connecting to a compute cluster and it does not forward on my auth keys to the other servers.